# How to add options of ng2-toastr in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have use ng2-toastr, its work fine but I am does not found change the options of ng2-toastr. I am follow link [ng2-toastr](https://github.com/PointInside/ng2-toastr).
Please tell us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at node_moduls/ng2-toastr

there is a ng2-toastr.css

maybe you can do here some magic but i am not really an expert at css

but i see that there is some positioning like top-center.

you can use this style classes like this

```
    export class CustomOption extends ToastOptions {
  animate = 'flyRight'; // you can override any options available
  newestOnTop = false;
  showCloseButton = true;
}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr#toastoptions-configurations

Use dependency inject for custom configurations. You can either inject into app.module.ts or any component class.